# GAE filter by missing repeated property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to query for all objects that have no value for a given repeated property.

For example imagine you have the following model:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    bar = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
```

and you wanted all the instances of Foo where bar had no value, or is []. How would you perform this query or work around this behavior?

Note (from GAE's ndb documentation):

> Querying for a value of None on a repeated property has undefined
>   behavior; don't do that

Answer (score 1):

Well, like the docs say, you can't.

One way of approaching this might be to keep another property on the model that records how many values it has in bar. You would need to update this when the entity is saved: a good way would be to override `put()` to do `self.bar_count = len(self.bars)` before calling the superclass method.

Of course, you'd then need to go through your existing data to set the counts; you might want to use a [mapper](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) to do that.

Comment: Sounds like `bar_count` should be a `ComputedProperty` to simplify the application code (so that on-the-fly computation happens automatically at `put` with no need to override).